# How would you show that $ℝv=\{tv\mid t \in ℝ\}$ is a subspace of $ℝ^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

These are my steps:

1. $0$ is certainly in $ℝ^n$
2. If $at \in ℝ$, then $atv=t(av)=ℝ(av)=a(ℝv)$
3. If $t+s \in ℝ$, then $(t+s)v=tv+sv=ℝ(tv+sv)=(ℝt+ℝs)v$.

Since I felt my steps are partly erroneous, could anyone fix it please?

Comment: You wrote $t(av)=\mathbb R(av)$, which is false.

Answer (score 2):

The vector space axioms are stated in a certain way which you are violating in 2 and 3.

In general, given a vector space $V$ and a subset $W \subset V$, in defining "$W$ is a subspace of $V$" here is what the abstract versions of 2 and 3 say, together with the way you should write that for your particular example:

Item 2 in the abstract:

- If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $w \in W$ then $aw \in W$

Item 2 for your example:

- If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $tv \in \mathbb{R}v$, then $a(tv) \in \mathbb{R}v$, because $a(tv) = (at)v \in \mathbb{R}v$.

Item 3 in the abstract:

- If $u,w \in W$ then $u+w \in W$.

Item 3 for your example:

- If $tv,sv \in \mathbb{R}v$ then $tv + sv \in \mathbb{R}v$, because $tv + sv = (t+s)v \in \mathbb{R}v$.

Comment: Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit more knowledge about linear mappings one can do it without having to check the vector space axioms:

with $$\varphi_t:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R^n,~v\mapsto t\cdot I_n\cdot v = \begin{pmatrix} t & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 & t & \ldots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & t \end{pmatrix}\cdot v$$ we get that $\mathbb Rv=\operatorname{im}(\varphi_t)$ and thus, as the image of a linear mapping, it is a vector space.